# Enable wifi option disappeard

Tags: wireless, network-manager

Until recently I had Ubuntu 15.04 working fine.
A few days ago however the "enable wifi" option disappeared from my Connection icon menum and I am not able to connect to wifi.
Strange enough when I chose "advanced options for Ubuntu" in the grub, and chose an older version, then the option "enable wifi" was there, and working perfectly fine.
From there I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.10 hoping that would solve it, but .. It didn't. No "enable wifi" option in the connection menu, no access to wifi.
Even worse: no older versions to be found in the grub advanced options any more no way back as it seems.
What can I do to get the wifi back?
Btw, I have tried to disable/enable networkmanager via terminal, and even in settings/software&updates/additional drivers, without any visible effect.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Update to a supported version as 15.10 goes EOL today

Comment: Thanks Pilot6 for your effort. The result of lspci -knn | grep Net -A2 is:

merlin@merlin-Lenovo-B50-30:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0621]
 Kernel driver in use: wl

This is however AFTER that I followd Orions advice to disable Secure Boot in BIOS. I don't know whether it would have been something else with Secure boot enabled. Thanks again for your opinion and advice.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy31 for your comment. I should do that soon.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello,**

I had the same problem on my 14.04 LTS but the problem occured after update.

**Try disabling secure boot in BIOS**. After hours of fixing this worked for me.

Hope I helped

-orion-

Comment: Thanks you Orion for your help! Amazingly it seems to do the trick! Any idea why this may have happened (I never had problems before, and not aware of deliberately having changed anything) and why this works? I'm very glad it works, would be nice to have a clue why ;-).

Comment: This issue occured for me after update. Manufacturer can set a list of hardware that is compatible with your machine. Secure boot enables (proper) hardware to communicate with the system. In your case wireless card was turned down by secure boot. The update I was talking about was about secure boot modification (if I remember correctly).